# properly setting the percentage height of a parent div and children divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm trying to figure this out without making to much of a mess here. I have one container div
then within it i have 3 more divs for wich are floated left. My problem is that my container div has a style of height of 100%.
like this

```
.Container {
height: 100%;
min-width: 600px;
overflow-y: hidden;
 }
```

and the one of my child div inside the container div(sidebar1), (for the sake of clarity ill keep it to just one div) has this css.

```
 border: 1px solid #E0E0DF;
bottom: 10px;
box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #888888;
float: left;
height: 100%;
overflow-y: scroll;
width: 18%;
  }
```

I add "list" elements to the sidedar1 div using jquery.The problem that I'm encountering is that i don't actually get the scroll bar to appear until there are like 3 or 4 items past the view and even when the scroll bar show up I can't scroll all the way down to see them. I understand it has something to so with the parent being 100% height and the child also being 100%. I cant see the bottom of the sidebar1 scroll plus i have the scroll bar hidden for container div. what is the best way to do this? i want to have  container div that basically expand the full length and width of the users screen without any scroll bars and then within it i would like to have my child divs floated left but i don't want  them to lose view if that makes any sense. I would like to be able to see their full scroll bar when they appear.
Thanks in advance
Miguel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your container isn't "aware" of its children, because they are floated. Use the clearfix solution on your container to contain the floats and you should properly get the scrollbar.

Take care though, as you will get the scrollbar from the first item, because the content of the container will have height 100% + 2px from the border. You can solve that by setting the box-sizing property on the floated elements to border-box.

Clearfix main idea:

```
.clearfix:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
}
```

Some link: http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html

Comment: sorry for the stupid question i added the clearfix  to the parent div and it seems that i can see the top half of the end of the scrollbar on the child div now, but i still cant see it all I'm missing something?

Comment: You should edit the question to provide a live simplified example with your problem (using JsBin, JsFiddle or other dedicated services). I'm afraid i can't help anymore without the example.

Comment: as crazy as it may sound i cant get jsfiddle to even show the scroll bar for the child div. i get one scroll bar on the outside for the parent/parent element. check it out http://jsfiddle.net/mRVn5/

Comment: You need this style: `html, body {
    height:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}`. At the moment #container has height as a percentage of something with no defined height, thus it defaults to auto - the height of its content.

Comment: thanks this is futile. you answer comes close what to im trying to do i just need to get a better understanding of css. back to the drawing board.